# Change back to Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Windows back on my computer. But when I boot from my USB containing windows and I come to the point to format my drive, I can't because it's not in a NTFS format or something.

I have two drives, one SSD and one for bulking files. The SSD is the one holding the OS and needs to be wiped and replaced with windows. The other drive I have all backup stuff on, so I don't want to erase that.

How can I go about this? All guides suggest I should be able to format my drive and install from the Windows USB, but in my case I can't.

Comment: This is a windows related question. Your problem is with formatting a disk to NTFS. " and I come to the point to format my drive, I can't because it's not in a NTFS format or something. " No, you are trying to -install- windows on a not-NTFS system, that is when you get an error notice. Formatting is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) to wipe your SSD and format it as NTFS first and then install Windows.

Gparted runs live off a USB stick and has a very nice graphical interface for partitioning and formatting drives. [Download](http://gparted.org/download.php) GParted ISO, burn to bootable USB, and boot from USB.

My experience of Windows disk manager is that it's very limited. So I imagine that the Windows boot drive's partitioning function is also.